# Parsing json on gwt

Tags: json, gwt

Server returns json in this fromat:

```
{
"appTarget":
    {
        "id":"3",
        "teacher_id":"2",
        "class_code":"0000",
        "target_id":"2",
        "course_id":"1",
        "from_date":"2011-08-03",
        "to_date":"2011-09-16",
        "wpm":"30",
        "acc":"43",
        "success_per":"0",
        "name":"Basic Course"
    }
}
```

On gwt side i created JS overlay class named JTarget

and this class's atributes are the same to th json which comes from server.

My question is how can I initialize new JTarget object from coming json text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedJSON

Comment: horribly outdated link. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html

Answer (score 0):

[`JsonUtils`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html) is what you're looking for.

```java
JTarget target = JsonUtils.safeEval(strFromServer);
```

(though I suspect your JTarget is actually for the inner object, so you'd have to create one overlay for the container object, with a `JTarget getAppTarget()` property)